# How to show my app as a printer so users can use it as a virtual printer?

Tags: c#, windows

I am making an application which will act as a virtual printer saving the printed document to a file.
How can I make my app appear as a printer in the print dialog?

Thanks, Jason

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a Windows Printer Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649490/writing-a-windows-printer-driver)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to write a printer driver for this, you will not be able to do this in C#. You will at the very least need to use C/C++ and the [WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557573%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Windows Driver Kit), there are commercial libraries/tools that make writting drivers easier.

If you are interested, a good online resource is
http://www.osronline.com/