# create a virtual printer

Tags: c#

I am trying to Create a Application in C# which will take any type of file and convert it into    Pdf.
I want to add this application in windows "printer and settings" as i have shown in below image.
novapdf  is a virtual printer whose final output is pdf.

1)how can i add my application to "printer and settings"?

2)I want my Custom Properties when my Printer is selected.

please Help.

[image]

Comment: Why did you tag this for SQL Server?

Comment: because i was using it. not for this application.

Comment: Have a look at [Writing a Windows Printer Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649490/writing-a-windows-printer-driver)